# What is the idiomatic way in TypeScript to extend an object (already implementing an interface) to a wider interface?

Tags: typescript

I have these DTO interfaces in TypeScript:

```
interface ProductDto {
    readonly productId: number;
    readonly name     : string;
}

interface FirstPartyProductDto extends ProductDto {
    readonly foo: string;
    readonly bar: number;
}
```

My application primarily uses server-side rendering but behaves like an SPA (this project is not using any SPA frameworks like Angular, Vue, etc). To aid the *rehydration*-process when the browser loads the page additional data is rendered to `data-` attributes.

So if a page contains a list-of-products, it would be rendered like so:

```
<ul class="productsList">
    <li
        data-product-id="1"
        data-product-name="Exploding toilet seat"
    >
    </li>
    <li
        data-product-id="2"
        data-product-name="Brussels sprout dispenser"
    >
    </li>
    <li
        data-product-id="3"
        data-product-name="Battery-tester tester"
    >
    </li>
</ul>
```

And the TypeScript to rehydrate `ProductDto` is straightforward:

```
static loadProductFromHtmlElement( e: HTMLElement ): ProductDto {
    return loadProductFromDataSet( e.dataset );
}

static loadProductFromDataSet( d: DOMStringMap ): ProductDto {
    return {
        productId: parseInt( d['productId']!, 10 ),
        name     : d['productName']!
    };
}
```

Now, supposing I want to rehydrate `FirstPartyProductDto` instances, then my code currently looks like this:

```
static loadFirstPartyProductFromDataSet( d: DOMStringMap ): FirstPartyProductDto {
    const productDto = loadProductFromDataSet( d );
    return {
        // ProductDto members:
        productId: productDto.productId,
        name     : productDto.name,

        // FirstPartyProductDto members:
        foo      : d['foo']!,
        bar      : parseInt( d['bar']!, 10 )
    };
}
```

I don't like how my code manually repeats the members of `ProductDto` as it populates the new returned object.

If this were untyped JavaScript, I could simply extend the existing `productDto` object instead:

```
static loadFirstPartyProductFromDataSet( d: DOMStringMap ): FirstPartyProductDto {
    const productDto = loadProductFromDataSet( d );
    productDto.foo = d['foo']!;
    productDto.bar = parseInt( d['bar']!, 10 );
    return productDto;
}
```

But the above code won't work because `productDto` is typed as `ProductDto` and so doesn't have the `foo` and `bar` properties, and even if I cast `productDto` as `FirstPartyProductDto` TypeScript won't let me assign those properties because they're `readonly`.

The only alternative I can immediately think of is to just cast `productDto` to `any`, but that means losing type-safety altogether.

There is also both `Object.assign` and the object spread operator `...` which TypeScript supports, which certainly improves `loadFirstPartyProductFromDataSet` by avoiding the need to type-out all of the inherited properties...

```
function loadFirstPartyProductFromDataSet( d: DOMStringMap ): FirstPartyProductDto {
    const productDto = loadProductFromDataSet( d );
    return {
        ...productDto,

        foo: d['foo']!,
        bar: parseInt( d['bar']!, 10 )
    };
}
```

...but it's still copying properties and values to a new object rather than setting properties on the existing object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing `readonly` properties prevent is explicitly setting a property value.  They don't affect assignability; you can assign a value of type `{a: string}` to a variable of type `{readonly a: string}` and vice versa (see [microsoft/TypeScript#13447](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13347) for more information).  That means we can use a type function like

```
type Mutable<T> = { -readonly [K in keyof T]: T[K] };
```

which strips `readonly` off properties, and write a version of the code you tried using a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) (which is what you are calling a "cast"):

```
static loadFirstPartyProductFromDataSetAssert(d: DOMStringMap): FirstPartyProductDto {
    const productDto = Blah.loadProductFromDataSet(d) as Mutable<FirstPartyProductDto>;
    productDto.foo = d.foo!;
    productDto.bar = parseInt(d.bar!, 10);
    return productDto;
}
```

That's probably the easiest way to proceed.  It isn't perfectly type safe, though, and you have to take care to actually set the asserted extra properties:

```
static loadFirstPartyProductFromDataSetAssertBad(d: DOMStringMap): FirstPartyProductDto {
    const productDto = Blah.loadProductFromDataSet(d) as Mutable<FirstPartyProductDto>;
    productDto.foo = d.foo!;
    // oops, forgot bar
    return productDto; // no error here
}
```

---

You could get a little more safety with a user-defined [assertion function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions) representing the gradual narrowing of an object type when you add properties, called `set(obj, key, val)`.  It would be used like this:

```
static loadFirstPartyProductFromDataSet(d: DOMStringMap): FirstPartyProductDto {
    const productDto = Blah.loadProductFromDataSet(d);
    // const productDto: ProductDto
    set(productDto, "foo", d['foo']!);
    // const productDto: {
    //   readonly productId: number;
    //   readonly name: string;
    //   foo: string;
    // } 
    set(productDto, "bar", parseInt(d['bar']!, 10));
    // const productDto: {
    //   readonly productId: number;
    //   readonly name: string;
    //   foo: string;
    //   bar: number;
    // } 
    return productDto; // okay
 }
```

And you can verify that it would give you an error if you left out `"bar"`.  The particular `set()` I used is defined as:

```
function set<T extends { [k: string]: any } & { [P in K]?: never }, K extends PropertyKey, V>(
    obj: T, key: K, val: V
): asserts obj is Extract<(T & Record<K, V> extends infer O ? { [P in keyof O]: O[P] } : never), T> {
    (obj as any).key = val;
}
```

This might be too complicated for your purposes, but I just wanted to demonstrate that it is possible to write code that adds properties to existing variables and get the type system to understand what you're doing.

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.0.2#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-LxsVxBhQIggcoAAORxVAYNgtDVkERdPFJaMTXXPtiDpBkoCZFl7yHEcxwPABBZILCPBhT3PS9r1vBhGMZZlLHvJsn3QxBKjAAlEEgxsuROLse3otjd04qdiHiTYyCNE0zQtcTmMk1k8MFBxKK-azvj2aUfhOYgnJlWC7NWFTOTgPY1U0E4AIZVBgMPNyAvgxBkPiLzW3bJAfIfOA7OXZ81xgeN6PMlipLw9i9wndAeJSKAQyBfiTzPC8WHYES6xyyzpMfMivAUpSkqbdSI17TdtOHQqDyPAytkNY1TXNDBGtYhy4Fs1rPE6xznOORA3OczyFsQAB6bbvDMZAdGlJg2DgKBEACrbXwS5TZvOHa9rAH4NBMTRww0VA0LSmjY0yjcgWmvKfygArdPCgTquEm8GvpCSZuBmStva86lpcxANN6-tgdB-c9NirbdvkhAOtmhhmrgLb5ycVGdAAImc2mdBw5ySPx59VkJ5HboR74GFk9DCbRMUHSSv9EDABEkSYOLPEFxB7QlLEiLlWriQJvbPGclWiRlh6pkpqcacQWmAsZ5TANCkDwICkjEJQtm5M54mUdJj8WzlhXJVF48Jc1aX1dFDFFfF5XGFV3W5a1sOdYDzwAo1KWI724QrvQG7Ufuwm4Bobg+DItLBCAA)